# Install a NPAPI Plugin in Safari on MacOS

Tags: macos, safari, npapi, browser-plugin

I have a NPAPI plugin that communicates with chipdrives to sign data. It does not display anything. The plugin supports the NPAPI interface. I can install it in Firefox, packaged as a XPI file. I can install it in Chrome using a CRX file. I have a CAB for IE. Works on MacOS for Chrome and Firefox too. The only unsupported browser by now is the Safari Browser. (And Opera but noone cares).

How do I have to package the plugin that it can be installed in safari on MacOS?

Comment: For Safari it depends on the type of work you want to deploy. Extension(`xar` files with name `*.safariext`) and Plug-ins are NPAPIs or Webkit-Plugins (kind of deprecated) different things. But you can bundle it in Apple-manier like every other app with given structure and info.plist

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a single installer (`.pkg` etc.) for all browsers by following Apples [install instructions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/InternetWeb/Conceptual/WebKit_PluginProgTopic/Concepts/AboutPlugins.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/30001248-BAJGJJAH).

Comment: Thank you, I have seen this page already. The sample contains a line like: "CODEBASE="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab". I can't believe that Safari unpacks and installs plugins that were packed with a microsoft tool. Or is there a cab archiever in OSX that is not mentioned?

A .pkg is what? Or a .dmg? What should we tell the customer when he enters the page? Download and install this software package out of the browser, then come back?

There seems to be no way to install a plugin from directly inside safari. If this is right, we drop support for the safari.

Comment: The .cab is for Windows/IE. A .pkg is an installer - as far as i know Safari has no way to achieve cab-/xpi-like installation. Even Flash delivers stand-alone installers.